# Observable item has zero element in knockout Binding

Tags: breeze, knockout-2.0

I am running into wired problem, the Record count of Array is 8 before and after applying the custom binding, but when Debugging the the binding they Array is empty. since array is empty the Grid is not displaying anything. What am i doing wrong?

```
var vM = {
            recordsCount: ko.observable(),
            countries: ko.observableArray()
        };
        $(function () {

        getAllCountries();

        // Handler for .ready() called.
        //alert(myns.JavaScript1);
        //alert(myns.JavaScript1);
        //alert(myns.JavaScript2);

    });


    var serviceName = "/breeze/CountriesBreeze/";
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

    /***  supporting functions ***/
    function getAllCountries() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("GetCountries");
        console.log("Getting Countries");
        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function(data) {
                vM.countries(data.results);
                alert(vM.countries().length);
                ko.applyBindings(vM);
                alert(vM.countries().length);
            }).fail(
                alert( "Error getting Data")
            )
    }


</script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

]

```
                   }">
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `ko.applyBindings()` statement to here:

```
var vM = {
            recordsCount: ko.observable(),
            countries: ko.observableArray()
        };
        $(function () {

        getAllCountries();

        // Handler for .ready() called.
        //alert(myns.JavaScript1);
        //alert(myns.JavaScript1);
        //alert(myns.JavaScript2);

    });

ko.applyBindings(vM);
```

Then I'm not sure if just doing `vM.countries(data.results)` will work, you may need to either iterate and push each value or do:

```
vM.countries(data.results)
vM.countries.valueHasMutated()
```